# Changing caption numbering for algorithm in algorithm2e

Tags: numbering, algorithm2e

I am trying to define a new environment that uses the `algorithm` environment from `algorithm2e`.  I want to use a separate caption counter for this new environment.  As of now, this is what I have, but I don't know how to `\def` or `\renewcommand` the caption variable with the `hdps` counter?

```
\newcounter{hdps}
\newenvironment{asm}{%
\stepcounter{hdps}%
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{ASM Spec.}%
\begin{algorithm}}
{%
\def\thealgocf{}%
\end{algorithm}}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want your algorithms to be sequentially numbered with a chapter, or section, or just have a number on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\newcounter{hdps}
\newenvironment{asm}
  {\refstepcounter{hdps}%
    \renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{ASM Spec.}%
    \begin{algorithm}\renewcommand\thealgocf{\arabic{hdps}}}
  {\end{algorithm}\addtocounter{algocf}{-1}}
```

EDIT: of course, this approach will only work as expected if `\caption` is used consistently in the `algorithm` and `asm` environments.

Comment: To get the float placement to work properly, I'd make a minor change:

    \newcounter{hdps}
    \newenvironment{asm}
      {\refstepcounter{hdps}%
        \renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{ASM Spec.}%
        \renewcommand\thealgocf{\arabic{hdps}}\begin{algorithm}}
      {\end{algorithm}\addtocounter{algocf}{-1}}

Answer (score 1):

Using an environment within an environment is sometimes problematic. See the related post [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14683/5764). In that sense, rather than defining a new environment and using a separate counter, I suggest using the counter provided by the `algorithm` environment: `algocf`, and modify both the algorithm name (from `Algorithm` to `ASM Spec.`) and the counter style (if needed). For example,

```
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{ASM Spec.}% Algorithm name
\usepackage{dcounter}% http://ctan.org/pkg/dcounter
\countstyle{<section>}%
\DeclareDynamicCounter{algocf}% <- algocf will be 'dynamic' within <section>
```

will reset the `algocf` counter within `<section>` (which could be any sectional unit that you specify, for example `chapter`, or `section`, or `subsection`, or `subsubsection`). This also redefines the presentation of the counter to be `\the<section>.\arabic{algocf}`.

Of course, this will not work if you want two different style algorithms (say named `Algorithm` and `ASM Spec.`).