# How does LaTeX implement environments?

Tags: environments

Do you know how LaTeX implements environments? To be more precise, what does

```
\newenvironment{<env-name>}[<n-args>][<default>]{<begin-code>}{<end-code>}
```

in terms of TeX commands (i.e., how is the LaTeX command `\newenvironment` defined in TeX)?

Comment: Please have a look at [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14684/2975) where I show and discuss the internal definitions of `\begin` and `\end`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command `\newenvironment{<env-name>}[<n-args>][<default>]{<begin-code>}{<end-code>}` is equivalent to:

```
\newcommand{\<env-name>}[<n-args>][<default>]{<begin-code>}
\newcommand{\end<env-name>}{<end-code>}
```

The reason is that `\begin{<env-name>}...\end{<env-name>}` is transferred into

```
<check whether the command \<env-name> exists
\begingroup
\csname <env-name>\endcsname % this is a way to call macro \<env-name> by its name
...
<check whether the inner-most environment is really <env-name>
\csname end<env-name>\endcsname % calls \end<env-name>
\endgroup
```

The problem is that you cannot do `\newcommand{\#1}...` so the command `\csname...\endcsname` is actually used by `\newenvironment` to overcome this problem.

The exact definition of `\newenvironment` is very complicated since the presence of `*` (that indicate the environment to be defined without `\long`), presence of `[<n-args>]` and `[<default>]` has to be tested, which in the terms of LaTeX means a lot of inner macros. To explore the details, you can run the following short source code that shows the macro definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\parskip2ex
\makeatletter
\ttfamily
\meaning\newenvironment   % <-- put any macro name here
\par
\meaning\newcommand   % <-- put any macro name here
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should "transferred into" be "expanded into"?

Comment: Remark: `\begin{X}` is expanded/executed strictly before `\end{X}`, and in some special cases (`verbatim` environment for example) `\end{X}` is read as-is without any expansion, and the begin command (macro) uses it to delimit the end of the environment.