# Redefine environment to be a synonym for another

Tags: environments, description

I have a document with many `description` environments. I would like to change all these `description` environments to `LaTeXdescription` environments, without manually changing all the occurrences of `description`.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX that I want the `description` environment to be just a synonym for `LaTeXdescription`?

Comment: @user202729 Actually, the question you suggest was asked 6 month later. So basically this question here can't be the duplicate.

Comment: @Roland while the wording of the banner suggests otherwise ("this question has been asked _before_") it is fine to close a question as a duplicate of a later one. The idea is to choose the best/most complete/easiest to understand question as the duplicate target, which is not necessarily the oldest. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha with the answer of Shog9 who is a (now former) Stack Exchange staff member.

Comment: @Marijn I'm probably biased, but it seems to me that both the question and the answers in this question ("the one closed as duplicate") are better from the point of view of clarity and conciseness. In fact this question has 10k views compared to 5k views of the other.

Comment: @gioele either direction of closure would be ok for me in this case, I agree that this question is more concise but the other question provides useful extra information. However, my point in the previous comment was not to give my opinion on which question should be closed, just to remark that the reasoning in Roland's comment (this question is older so it can't be the one closed as duplicate) is not an existing rule or valid argument.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work:

```
\renewenvironment{description}{%
    \begin{LaTeXdescription}%
}{%
    \end{LaTeXdescription}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add `\ignorespacesafterend` as the last token in the end code if you define it that way as the nested environment form defeats LaTeX's white space handling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I will remember your advice. Is there a big difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: As always with newcommand and let the main difference is if the definition of LaTeXdescription is later changed. If it is changed then your definition will pick up the new version, mine will pick up the old. I suppose we will find out which one the OP wants by who gets the green tick. I +1 yours anyway as it is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: This is not the best idea: see [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: I want to add that `\ignorespacesafterend` also helps pandoc to process such a latex fragment. In fact, pandoc 2.18 then deals a lot better with environments redefined in this way when they are nested in list items.

Answer (score 19):

It depends a bit on how you define , specifically whether you define it in terms of the existing `description` but assuming `LaTeXdescription` is not defined to expand to something involving `description` you should be able to do

```
\let\description\LaTeXdescription
\let\enddescription\endLaTeXdescription
```

Comment: Note that if the environment name contain a star you may need ``\catcode `*=11`` ... ``\catcode `*=12``.