# newenvironment : synonym for an existing environment

Tags: environments

As in this example [Redefine environment to be a synonym for another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82859/redefine-environment-to-be-a-synonym-for-another) I want to have a synonym for an existing environment. So I created `bigSystEquation` being an `align*` environment. (In order to don't have to know that I use `align*`)

But the code below gives me an error :
the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{align*} on input line 10 ended by \end{bigSystEquation}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13    \end{bigSystEquation}
```

And if I change the line 13 by `\end{align*}` (just curiosity, it has no sense to do so)

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{bigSystEquation} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}
.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{document}
```

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\newenvironment{bigSystEquation}{\begin{align*}}{\end{align*}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bigSystEquation}
        a &= b\\
        c &= d \\
    \end{bigSystEquation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [`newenvironment`: error with `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236664/5764)

Comment: ...the other option is to define the environment using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ): `\NewEnviron{bigSystEquation}{\begin{align*} \BODY \end{align*}}`