# Including an optional answer in an exam paper

Tags: indentation, verbatim

I would like to include answers in an exam paper so that the paper could be compiled in two different ways: with and without the answers.  The way this is usually done in British universities (or at least some of them) is to use the `comment` package, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{answer}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{\renewenvironment{answer}{\begin{answershown}}{\end{answershown}}}
\newenvironment{answershown}{\textbf{Answer:} }{}
% \showanswers  % comment out to hide the answer
\begin{document}
  Is the following command correct?
  \begin{verbatim}
    public class
  \end{verbatim}
  \begin{answer} % do not indent!
    The following command is not correct:
    \begin{verbatim}
      public class
    \end{verbatim}
  \end{answer} % do not indent!
\end{document}
```

Here `\showanswer` is a toggle between the clean version of the paper (without the answers) and the version containing the answers. The disadvantage is that the `comment` package does not allow indentation (which is important in that it clearly shows the structure, potentially complicated, of the paper), and so compiling the source code above produces an error message:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> ./mwe.tex

?
```

To allow indentation, I can use the `environ` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{answer}{}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{\RenewEnviron{answer}{\textbf{Answer:} \BODY}}
\showanswers  % comment out to hide the answer
\begin{document}
  Is the following command correct?
  \begin{verbatim}
    public class
  \end{verbatim}
  \begin{answer}
    The following command is not correct:
    \begin{verbatim}
      public class
    \end{verbatim}
  \end{answer}
\end{document}
```

But `environ` does not like `verbatim` in the answer, and compiling the latter source code produces:

```
Runaway argument?
 public class \end {verbatim}\env@ignore  The following command is no\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> ./mwe.tex

?
```

Is there a way to have both indentation and `verbatim` (in answers)?

Comment: Any reason you don't use lstlisting to draw the code? I think to remember verbatim does not like being in many things ^^ Also, to indent you may find `adjustwidth` useful.

Comment: Just don't use `environ` and use the normal `\newenvironment` from LaTeX, which does not grab the whole environment at once. (or if you *really* need to grab it use `cprotEnv`, but may be overkill)

Comment: @tobiasBora: I am still getting an error when using lstlisting: `Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 19. ...` (It says "warning" but in fact the system enters into a dialogue with me which I can't leave without simply closing the window.)  I have tried both `listings` and `mcode` packages.  But for my purpose it would be good to be able to deal with `verbatim` as well: I would like my colleagues to use my style file, and some of them like `verbatim`.

Comment: @user202729: I do not know how to remove the body of the environment in `\newenvironment` (which I need in the clean version of the exam paper).  (Things like `\iffalse\fi` did not work for me.)  And no success with `cprotEnv` so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are several possible solutions. (you can use either one of the first 2)

I rewrite them into separate questions (future readers are more likely to search for these terms).

---

### How can I define a "comment" environment such that the environment delimiter can be indented?

Easy, use `verbatim` package.

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\let\answer=\comment
\let\endanswer=\endcomment
```

Reference: [Redefine environment to be a synonym for another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82859/redefine-environment-to-be-a-synonym-for-another)

Note that it's actually possible to indent environments defined by `comment` package with tab, only space fails.

Alternatively:

- use `version` package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325928/250119
- use `memoir` documentclass. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29061/250119

---

### How can I redefine an environment defined by the `environ` package, such that it allows catcode-changing commands (e.g. `\verb`, `\begin{verbatim}`) in its body?

There's nothing special with environments defined by the `environ` package. You can still use `\renewenvironment` to redefine it as usual.

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{answer}{}

\newcommand{\showanswers}{\renewenvironment{answer}{\begin{answershown}}{\end{answershown}}}
\newenvironment{answershown}{\textbf{Answer:} }{}
```

---

Not that you need this one, but for reference:

### How can I *define* an environment with the `environ` package, such that it allows catcode-changing commands in its body?

You can't. There are alternatives like savebox or `scontents` package.

Reference: [Verbatim in environ’s \BODY](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `lstlisting` and `verbatim` plays with catcodes and can't really be used inside environments, at least when we want to be able not to display them. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but you can save your code before your environment inside a box using the package `realboxes` and the command `\Sbox{\mylstbox}{your content}` (make sure to create your box using `\newsavebox{\mylstbox}`) , and reuse it after inside your environment via `\usebox{\mylstbox}`. It works for both `verbatim` and `lstlisting`.

mode exam:

[image]

mode answers:

[image]

By the way, I think that tcolorbox also has a module for answers, you may like it (and I guess this solution also applies to tcolorbox mode).

```
%%% Comment/uncomment, or compile with:
%%%
%%% pdflatex -jobname=exam_answers "\def\showanswers{} \input{exam.tex}" && pdflatex -jobname=exam_no_answers "\input{exam.tex}"
%%%
%%% to produce automatically two versions without changing the file.
% \def\showanswers{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29971/why-can-lstlisting-not-be-saved-in-a-command
\usepackage{changepage} % For adjustwidth and indentation
\NewDocumentEnvironment{answer}{+b}{
  \ifdefined\showanswers
  \textbf{Answer}:

  \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm} % Indent
    #1
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \else\fi}{}
\newsavebox{\mylstbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent Is the following command correct?
\begin{lstlisting}
  public class
\end{lstlisting}
\Sbox{\mylstbox}{%
\begin{lstlisting}
public class {
  hello
}
\end{lstlisting}
}
\begin{answer}
  The following command is not correct:

  \usebox{\mylstbox}
\end{answer} % do not indent!
\end{document}
```