# I need help on forcing a pagebreak in LaTeX

Tags: page-breaking

I am using LaTeX and trying to put the tables and figures at the end of the manuscript so that they occur on separate pages. I have tried `\pagebreak`, `\newpage`, `\displaybreak` before each of the tables/figures and none of them are forced onto a new page. Help.

Comment: Can you post a short example? It could be an issue with the [float position](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures) in which case the ``[H]`` specifier would help.

Comment: Okay, I have a table, then another table. I want both of them on separate pages at the end of the manuscript. I can post all the details but basically it looks like this ...\bibliography stuff \endbibliography \vfill\pagebreak (or \eject or \newpage) \begin{table}[p] ... table stuff ...\end{table} followed by the same stuff for the second ... third .. etc tables and figures ... and nothing seems to force the tables or figures to the next page. As for being blast from the past, what would you recommend when they tell you your manuscript has to be typeset in AMSTeX?

Comment: `\begin{table}` looks like latex? are you sure you are using amstex (which is a separate non-latex format) not ams latex class such as amsart ??

Comment: TOTALLY DUH! I'm sorry, I meant LaTeX. It's been a long week with school starting again and my brain isn't working right. Yes LaTeX. But it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried \vfill\pagebreak[4] and that didn't work either

Comment: `\clearpage` will flush each float on to a new page

Comment: BRAVO David!!! Thank you so much. That worked. I will have to sit and figure out why it worked. But it worked. You get the gold star.

Comment: `\vfill` doesn't actually put anything on a page, and `\pagebreak` requires a non-empty page to actually break.  `\clearpage` puts an invisible, empty box on the page so there's something there for the float to interact with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton more to the point `\clearpage` unlike `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` explicitly invokes the output routine to flush all pending floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- good point.  of course.  (if you wanted to clear out one float at a time, you could do it the hard way, with `\vspace*{\fill}\newpage` after each one.  `\clearpage` is lots easier.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No vspace and `\newpage` have essentially no effect on the pending floats, they may just stay in the pending lists until a more suitable page comes along.

Comment: Well, whatever it does, once I put a \clearpage after each figure and table, it worked beautifully. Guess I have a whole lot more to learn about TeX.

Comment: @tmwitten -- don't be discouraged.  i seem to have a lot to learn too, and i've been at it a lot longer.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 39):

`\clearpage` will flush each float on to a new page

Comment: What does "flush each float" mean exactly?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson `\clearpage` is the same as `\newpage` except that after the page break any pending figures, tables etc are forced to appear at that point and not allowed to float further, it "clears" or "flushes" the list of unplaced floats.

Answer (score 5):

The package `endfloat` will move all floats to the end; setting `totalnumber` to 1 will ensure only one float per page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{4cm}{0pt}}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2cm}\rule{4cm}{0pt}}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\rule{4cm}{0pt}}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{4cm}{0pt}}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the package [endfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) is for.

Comment: yes.. I initially made (but didn't post) a comment saying exactly this, but then as OP already has the figures at end of document in the source, just flushing them out seemed more efficient, although in general endfloat seems to work quite well for this. (+1:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My suspicion is that the OP put all figures at the end of the document in the ``.tex`` file because (s)he is unaware of ``endfloat``.

Comment: Sure, but once they are there, they're there:-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old post, but so far I couldn't find the solution anywhere and believe to have solved this, so I thought posting it here might help. I did it for setting a song book with the guitar environment, but the concept should be transferable.
Here is what I did:

```
%define new pagestyle for hint
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{fancyNext}[fancy]{\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\Large{\textbf{See next page}}}}

\usepackage{guitar}
 
\newcounter{myguitar} % counter for unique labels in each instance of new environment myguitar
% new environment "myguitar" which is basically the guitar environment, 
%   but sets the labels myguitar-start/end-\themyguitar at begin and end,
%   then checks the pagenumbers of the labels and changes the pagestyle 
%   if they are not equal
 
\newenvironment{myguitar}{%     
    \begin{guitar}\label{myguitar-start-\themyguitar} %
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{myguitar-start-\themyguitar}<\getpagerefnumber{myguitar-end-\themyguitar}%
    \pagestyle{fancyNext}%
    \fi%
}{%
\pagestyle{fancyNext}\end{guitar}\label{myguitar-end-\themyguitar}%
}
```

Hope that helps some people ;)

Comment: Side note it's recommended to use the plain form when defining new environment [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)