# Is there any way to redefine fancyvrb Verbatim environment?

Tags: fancyvrb

I am trying to comment out all Verbatim blocks that are generated from a jupyter notebook export to .tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim} % for comment
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\let\showVerbatim\Verbatim
\let\endshowVerbatim\endVerbatim
\def\Verbatim{\begin{comment} \showVerbatim}
\def\endVerbatim{\endshowVerbatim \end{comment}}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Display this

\begin{Verbatim}
Don't display this
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

But this fails with:

> Runaway argument?
>   ! File ended while scanning use of \next

I have read the fancyvrb manual and there are some bits there (FVE@Verbatim & \FV@VerbatimEnd) that seem promising, but I have been unable to get any of them to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Special case of [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual of `verbatim` states one has to use the “low level” calls:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\renewenvironment{Verbatim}{\comment}{\endcomment}

\begin{document}

Some text above
\begin{Verbatim}
abc
def
ghi
\end{Verbatim}

Some text below

\end{document}
```