# Define a new environment based on "proof"

Tags: environments

I want to change the word "Proof" as in `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` to "Solution". I found out that `\begin{proof}[Solution]...\end{proof}` could do the trick. But is there a way to define a new environment `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}` to make it automatic. I only need to change the word "Proof -> Solution". Everything else should stay the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
$A^2=B^2+C^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
$A=1, B=1, C=0$
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
$D^2=E^2+F^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}[Solution]
$D=1, E=1, F=0$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show a short compilable code you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wondering if you are only looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solution]}{\end{proof}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
$A^2=B^2+C^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
$A=1, B=1, C=0$
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
$D^2=E^2+F^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{solution}
$D=1, E=1, F=0$
\end{solution}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the best idea, prefer the `\proof` / `\endproof` when defining nested environment. [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)