# Can environments be redefined in beamer to accept slide numbers?

Tags: beamer, environments

I'd like the environmnets `align` and `align*` in my beamer document to accept slide numbers. For instance, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{align*}<2->
    a &= b & c &= d
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The desired behavior here would be for the content in my `align*` environment to appear from the second slide onward. I suspect this is possible because environments like `definition` and `block` work in precisely this way.

My guess is that something like the following syntax should work

```
\renewenvironment<>{align}{????}{????}
\renewenvironment<>{align*}{????}{????}
```

However, I can't quite figure out what to write to achieve my desired result.

I suppose one could generalize my question to ask if *any* built-in environment could be renewed to work in this way.

Comment: `beamer` offers `\newenvironment<>{⟨environment name⟩}[⟨argument number⟩][⟨default optional value⟩]{⟨begin text⟩}{⟨end text⟩}` in order to create overlay-aware environments. It should however be noted,  "that the implementation of `align` does wicked things" (see beamer manual page 24) See also section "23.4  Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise"  of the `beamer` manual.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose one could generalize my question to ask if any built-in environment could be renewed to work in this way.

In general you can use

```
\renewenvironment<>{center}
    {\begin{actionenv}#1\begin{originalcenter}}
    {\end{originalcenter}\end{actionenv}}
```

to make any well behaved environment overlay-aware

---

For the case of `align*`, it will be much better for your mental health to just wrap it into an `onlyenv`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{onlyenv}<2->
  \begin{align*}
    a &= b & c &= d
  \end{align*}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure about beamer, but normally you should use the plain form though. [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: @user202729 That's why I wrote "well behaved environment" :) You can use the same technique with plain form https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty#L406 but if an environment is so picky that it requires this, it will probably also not like the renaming to `original...`